# HERE Maps Mobile SDK Navigation and Xamarin

Tags: here-api

I develop mobile apps for iOS and Android using Xamarin.

1. Will HERE Maps mobile SDK work with Xamarin?
2. Is there full turn by turn navigation in the SDK, including voice instructions?
3. If using navigation with the mobile SDK, how is it billed, still based on transactions?

Answer (score 0):

1. We recommend using android studio. For Xamarin, bindings need to be created in SDK, which are not their in our existing roadmap. Hence you can either create the bindings yourself or using our professional services as SDK libraries need modification in this case.
2. Yes it is available
3. Please refer https://developer.here.com/pricing for exact pricing details.